# How to simplfy this function?

Tags: functions

I need help about this function

$$y = \frac 1 3x^3 - 2x^2 + 3x + 1$$

I know that the domain of this function is defined for all $x$ from $\mathbb R$ but I can't go on cause I don't know how to simplify this, I need just to simplify so I can do other, sorry for bad my English

Comment: If the function is defined for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ I suppose that it is $y=\frac{1}{3}x^3-2x^2+3x+1$ and there is nothing to simplify here.

Comment: What kind of simplification do you expect?  This form is quite simple.

Comment: but how can I find zeros if I don't simplify this?

Comment: First try rational root test https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your notation right, your function is
$$y=\frac{1}{3}x^3-2x^2+3x+1.$$
You probably want to find it's roots. $x$ is a root of $y=f(x)$ if and only if $x$ is a root of $3y=x^3-6x^2+9x+3.$

By the Rational Root Theorem, $x=p/q$ is a root of $3y$ if, and only if $p|3$ and $q|1$. Because only $1$ and $-1$ divide $1$, $x$ must be an integer. But then $x$ must be $\pm 1$ or $\pm 3$. However, none of these numbers are roots of $3y$, so it does not have any rational roots.

By the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, it surely has at least 1 real root. Unfortunately this root is not expressible in a simple form. (But you can always use Cardano's formula to calculate it.)

Comment: I still don't understand, in the solution it's says that this function have only one real zero in $x_0 \in (-1, 0)$, how? that is what I want to know

Comment: Have you ever heard of Bolzano's theorem?

Comment: Thanks for your help but I give up on this task, this is too much for me, I need to work on something simplier

Comment: It's cool! Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for roots, there are not [any nice ones](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3-6x%5E2%2B9x%2B3%3D0).  There is only one real root at $x=2-\left( \frac 2{5-\sqrt{21}}\right)^{1/3}-\left( \frac52-\frac{\sqrt{21}}2\right)^{1/3} \approx -0.279019$ and two complex ones.  Are you sure you have the right problem?